# how to both rotate and change colors in UIView animateKeyFramesWithDuration

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a spinner that is rotating correctly, but I'd also like to have it change rainbow colors while it spins.  How can I combine both a rotation animation with a color change animation in a key frame animation?  I am using PaintCode to render the assets as a vector art so I can draw the spinner in any color.

```
   func animate(){
        UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0, options:.CalculationModeLinear | .Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.333333, animations: { () -> Void in
                let rotation = (CGFloat) (2.0/3.0 * M_PI)
                self.spinner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.333333, relativeDuration: 0.333333, animations: { () -> Void in
                let rotation = (CGFloat) (4.0/3.0 * M_PI)
                self.spinner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.666667, relativeDuration: 0.333333, animations: { () -> Void in
                let rotation = (CGFloat) (0)
                self.spinner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)
            })

        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            //complete
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tintColor of the spinner. If you want to achieve a change that goes thorough the "rainbow colors" I do not think UIView.animate- would serve the purpose. I guess going with a timer based animation would be a better solution since you got to add a lot of UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime calls. And you might not know the exact number. Also if you want to add a new color you got to recalculate times and add a new call which is ...let's say not a good way to code :)
Can you give us an example of something similar to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: to make it simpler what if we use the same animation frame offsets but just add a color transformation to the animation  to make it go from blue - red - yellow